# Deepen inside an object dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an object like this:

```
state.variationsData = {
description:"Provar altas de CAN"
examples_edit: null
examples_new: null
examples_production: "[{\"text\": \"baby\"}, {\"text\": \"bajas de CAN en 
 productivo\"}, {\"text\": \"levantar can desde local\"}, {\"text\": 
 \"salvar cambios en can\"}, {\"text\": \"borrar datos en can\"}, 
 {\"text\":\"sustituir usuarios can\"}]"
 id: "#CA2_3"
 idResponse:"CA2_3"
}
```

I would like to get the examples edit, new, production, with a variable, to print in my react edit form.

i have this:

```
const retrieveVariations = useSelector(state => 
 state.variationsData.examples_(here i would like to use a variable with 
 (new, edit, production);
```

I have this variable, but i don't know how to insert in the route.

I tryed:

```
const retrieveVariations = useSelector(state => 
state.variationsData.examples_{variable});

const retrieveVariations = useSelector(state => 
state.variationsData.examples_+variable);

const retrieveVariations = useSelector(state => state.variationsData. 
[examples_+variable]);
```

Some suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[]` to define the key, then use a base string (`examples_`) with your desired variable (`variable`)

```
const retrieveVariations = useSelector(state => state.variationsData['examples_' + variable]);
```

Comment: yessss i saw it just after write the question. 
const retrieveVariations = useSelector(state => state.variationsData[`examples_${estado}`]) ;